# How do I prevent apps from blocking a second screen?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, root-access, xposed-framework, samsung-touchwiz, chromecast

I used Google cast to cast my phone's screen. That worked. But all4, the Channel 4 catch-up app, wouldn't display on the second screen. A message popped up saying "all 4 doesn't work on secondary screens". How can i stop the app from detecting this? I'm rooted and xposed, s5 touchwiz lollipop

Answer (score 1):

Try [xPrivacy](http://repo.xposed.info/module/biz.bokhorst.xprivacy).

You might be able to limit the permissions of the all4 application you mentioned in such a way that it cannot tell if Google cast is running.

The [Github](https://github.com/M66B/XPrivacy#usage) page has the full options on what is available.

Comment: Looks promising thanks. Don't have time to investigate properly, but as bounty is expiring tomorrow, decided to award it now. If you or anyone has a clue what permission to restrict, please do tell